# Как дождаться завершения нескольких потоков?

Tags: java

В цикле создаются несколько потоков

```
// Открыли соединение с базой
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            // Выполнили обращение к базе
        }
    }).start();
}
// Закрыли соединение с базой
```

Если я пытаюсь закрыть соединение с базой до того, как выполниться обращение из одного из потоков, то выбрасывается исключение. Как дождаться завершения всех потоков?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант на основе `thread.join()`:

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    threads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // ...
        }
    }));
}

for (Thread thread: threads) {
    thread.start();
}
for (Thread thread: threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

надо юзать TheadPool, ThreadPoolExecutor или закрывать бд в каждом из потоков

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, опоздал на 5.5 лет, но все же - есть класс java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier, в котором можно задать кол-во потоков, которое должно войти в него, чтобы он их всех пропустил дальше

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит посмотреть на этот [класс](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Либо по старинке использовать семафоры.